# How can I bind the Header of an TabItem with a text in my TabItem DataTemplate for the header?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tabs, tabcontrol

I create this Template for my TabItems in App.xaml file so that I can use a custom style for my TabItem's Headers.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabItemHeader" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">

                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="6" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.5" Padding="1" Margin="2,4,2,4">
                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="28" MinWidth="60" MinHeight="20" >
                            
                            <fa:FontAwesome Name="ItemIconXaml" FontSize="22" Margin="10,0" Foreground="#0C0239"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Name="ItemNamexaml" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#0C0239" FontFamily="Segoe Script"/>
                            <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Close" FontSize="18" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#CCA09F9F" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseDown="FontAwesome_MouseDown"/>
                                    
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the code behind of the window which is charge to display the TabControl with it's tabItems. So I'm dynamically adding TabItems to the TabControl.

```
public partial class Accueil : Window
{
    public Accueil()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Definition des contents des Tabitems

        AjouterPatientTabItem.Content = ajouterPatientUserControl;
        FacturesDuJourTabItem.Content = facturesDuJourUserControl;
        MainHomeTabItem.Content = mainHomeUserControl;
        RegistreTabItem.Content = registreUserControl;
        ParamètresTabItem.Content = paramètresUserControl;

        // Attribution des names des TabItem
        
        //Ajouter Patient TabItem
        AjouterPatientTabItem.Header = "Nouveau patient";
     //   AjouterPatientTabItem.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];
        

        //Facture du patient TabItem
        FacturesDuJourTabItem.Header = "Factures du jour";
      //  FacturesDuJourTabItem.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];

        //MainHome 
        MainHomeTabItem.Header = "Accueil";
      //  MainHomeTabItem.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];

        //Registre
        RegistreTabItem.Header = "Registre";
           
      //  RegistreTabItem.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];
        
        //Paramêtres 
        ParamètresTabItem.Header = "Paramètres";
        //  ParamètresTabItem.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];



        //

     //   TabControlItems.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["TabItemStyle"];
        TabControlItems.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyTabItemHeader"];

        displayedItems.Add(MainHomeTabItem);

        this.TabControlItems.ItemsSource = displayedItems;    
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> displayedItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> DisplayedItems
    {
        get { return displayedItems; }
        set { displayedItems = value; }
    }

    //Instanciation des Usercontrols 

    public Home ajouterPatientUserControl = new Home("Accueil", "Home");
    public FacturesDuJour facturesDuJourUserControl = new FacturesDuJour();
    public mainHome mainHomeUserControl = new mainHome();
    public Paramètres paramètresUserControl = new Paramètres();
    public Registre registreUserControl = new Registre();

    // Instanciation des Tabs items 

    public TabItem AjouterPatientTabItem = new TabItem();
    public TabItem FacturesDuJourTabItem = new TabItem();
    public TabItem MainHomeTabItem = new TabItem();
    public TabItem ParamètresTabItem = new TabItem();

    public TabItem RegistreTabItem = new TabItem();

    private void AccueilBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // MainHomeTabItem.IsSelected = true;

        if (!displayedItems.Contains(MainHomeTabItem))
        {
            displayedItems.Add(MainHomeTabItem);
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = MainHomeTabItem;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = MainHomeTabItem;
        }
    }

    private void FactureDuJourBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        // FactureDuJourTabItem.IsSelected = true;

        if (!displayedItems.Contains(FacturesDuJourTabItem))
        {
            displayedItems.Add(FacturesDuJourTabItem);
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = FacturesDuJourTabItem;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = FacturesDuJourTabItem;
        }          
    }

    private void QuitterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window Quitter = new QuitterMessageBox();
        Quitter.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void AjouterNouveauPatientBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // AccueilTabItem.IsSelected = true;

        if (!displayedItems.Contains(item: AjouterPatientTabItem))
        {
            displayedItems.Add(AjouterPatientTabItem);
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = AjouterPatientTabItem;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = AjouterPatientTabItem;
        }
    }

    private void RegistreBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // RegistreTabItem.IsSelected = true;

        if (!displayedItems.Contains(item: RegistreTabItem))
        {
            displayedItems.Add(RegistreTabItem);
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = RegistreTabItem;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = RegistreTabItem;
        
        }
    }

    private void parametresBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ParamètresTabItem.IsSelected = true;

        if (!displayedItems.Contains(item: ParamètresTabItem))
        {
            displayedItems.Add(ParamètresTabItem);
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = ParamètresTabItem;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControlItems.SelectedItem = ParamètresTabItem;
        }
    }

    private void Window_closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Window Quitter = new QuitterMessageBox();

        Quitter.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void AccueilTabCloseTabBtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {   
        displayedItems.RemoveAt(TabControlItems.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

In the Xaml of Accueil class I create a tabControl

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlItems" ItemsSource="{Binding displayedItems}">
                    

 </TabControl>
```

When I run the app I doesn't show the header text. It shows nothing.
Please help me on it.

Sorry if my english is not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the `DataContext` itself instead of trying to bind to a `Header` property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Name="ItemNamexaml"
           FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#0C0239" FontFamily="Segoe Script"/>
```

The `DataContext` of the root element in the `HeaderTemplate` is the value of the `Header` property.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `Binding` to `TabControl.ItemsSource` doesn't resolve. This is because  the property `displayedItems` cannot be found in the current `TabControl.DataContext`.

Add `this.DataContext = this;` to the constructor of `Accueil`:

```
public Accueil()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DataContext = this;
}
```

This way `Accueil` will be implicitly assigned to (inherited) `TabControl.DataContext`.

Alternatively e.g., in case you don't want to set the `DataContext` of the parent control and its children to `Accueil`, change the `Binding` to

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Accueil}, Path=displayedItems}" />
```

The `TabControl` should not be bound to a collection of `TabItem` (which are item containers), but to a collection of model classes. The `TabControl` will generate those containers internally, applying styles and templates automatically.